# Running softwares or games on machine that doesn't meet minimum requirements

Tags: requirements

Are there any side effects if i force running softwares or games on a machine that doesn't meet the minimum requirements(either hardware or software) on said software in long terms?

By side effects i mean something that affect the machine not how the software run, i.e. permanent damage to hardware or system environment, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things will happen...

1. The machine will run at full tilt, with the fans sounding ready for take-off... yet the game itself will run at a total crawl [this could lead to crash, BSOD, hard reboot or eventually component failure depending on how well the machine can cool itself], or
2. It will simply fail to run at all.

Without knowing specific details, not much more can be speculated.

Comment: So components failure is also a possibility if the machine can't cool the components. Is temperature the only cause for components failure in this case? Actually i have experience on running 3d rendering software on machine with weak gpu that doesn't meet the requirement, eventually the gpu stopped working and need replacement. But i'm not sure if it's because of me forcing to run the software or gpu is just to old and need replacement anyway because it's my office pc and i don't know the gpu ages.

Comment: Theoretically, all computers ought to be able to handle running at full load constantly. Practically, few are sufficiently well-designed for that to be true.

Comment: So the problem/effects except the one that directly affect how the software run is system reboot and components failure, right?